# Socket.io - Multiple connections when there should only be one per browser window

Tags: javascript, ios, sockets

I've noticed that when loading into my app it creates multiple socket connections.

This bug seems quite intermittent, I've been looking around for a solution but nothing seems to be working thus far.

**Here's my server-side code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'skin')));

serv.listen(8081);
console.log("Server started");

var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
var socketCount = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Socket ' + socketCount + ' connected');
    socketCount++;

    socket.emit('socketConnected', true);

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('Socket ' + socketCount + ' disconnected');
        socketCount--;
        delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
        delete PLAYER_LIST[socket.id];
    });

    ...
```

When refreshing the page, the disconnect function on the server fires, but only once despite the fact that there is supposedly several sockets. I then get multiple socket connecting, again.

When putting a breakpoint on the frontend (listening for `socketConnected`) it triggers multiple times. Can anyone point out any flaws in the code above that may cause this issue?

Thanks.

**New development after some further debugging:**

I've noticed that when I emit `socketConnected` as seen above, I have assumed that I am able to grab some further data from the frontend.

When sending data from the frontend back to the server again, I run my calculations on the server with it and then run a second `socket.emit('something ..` from the server to the frontend. - This takes several attempts before actually hitting a breakpoint on the frontend. During these attempts to emit the data from the server, this is where the several other connections are made.

However, if I wrap the second server emit in a `setTimeout` function it works fine and maintains the current connection without creating multiple more. Has anyone else encountered this issue? - If so, is there a solution that avoids using `setTimeout`?

Comment: What about `io.on()` rather than `io.sockets.on()`?

Comment: Good thinking. Unfortunately it's still connecting multiple times though.

Comment: `serv.listen()` is an asynchronous function that takes a callback; at the point where you log "Server started", the server has not started yet. Probably not related, but still something to keep in mind

Comment: Hm, well from what I can tell your backend code looks perfectly fine. What is the frontend doing? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: I have updated the question after some debugging Matt. I'm going to find an alternate solution to avoid using `setTimeout` tomorrow and hopefully let you know if I'm able to improve it.